# Regex for capturing 4 consecutive numbers in an ID

Tags: regex, string, regex-group, regex-greedy

I need a formula to start at a a certain index and then get the next 4 consecutive numbers.  Using REGEX.  And testing whether they are in the range of 0000-4999.

```
^.{6}\d{4}$[0000-4999]
```

This is some code I have tried.  Although I'm still new and don't understand regex.

The outcome needs to be as follows:

ID Number:

```
9202204720082
```

Get the following 4 numbers:  4720

Starting at index 7 (presuming indexes starts at 1)

So want to get numbers if indexes 7,8,9, and 10.
This is done to determine the gender in an ID.

Comment: What did you use `[0000-4999]` for? Use `^.{6}(\d{4})` and grab Group 1 value Else, use `(?<=^.{6})\d{4}` if your regex supports lookbehind and you need to get the result as a whole match by all means.

Comment: If you want to  use the anchors, `^\d{6}(\d{4})\d{3}$`. The `[0000-4999]` is a character class and is the same as `[012349]` but it is after the end of the string/line

Comment: I have updated my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

May be this can help :

```
(?<=\d{6})\d{4}(?<=\d{3})
```

you can check it out in the regex101 link : [Link to Regex](https://regex101.com/r/eYklpa/1/)

Comment: it works great, but how do i check whether those values are in a range of 0000-4999

Answer (score 0):

Your original expression is just fine, here we can slightly modify it to:

```
^.{6}(\d{4}).+$
```

which we are capturing our desired digits in this group `(\d{4})`.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qYo4p9/1/)

```js
const regex = /^.{6}(\d{4}).+$/gm;
const str = `9202204720082`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a regex for this. You could achieve the same result by simply getting a substring. Depending on your programming language you might do something like this:

### JavaScript

```js
var string = "9202204720082";
var index = 6;

console.log(string.substring(index, index + 4));
```

### Ruby

```rb
string = '9202204720082'
index = 6

string[index, 4]
#=> "4720"
```

### Perl

```pl
my $string = '9202204720082';
my $index = 6;

substr($string, $index, 4);
#=> "4720"
```

Comment: I'm working in Salesforce Validation Rules Editor unfortunately.